# Is +"" better than .toString()?

Tags: java, object-to-string

Since `myObject.toString()` fails when `myObject` is `null` (throws a `NullPointerException`), it is safer to do `myObject+""`, since it's essentially doing `String.valueOf(myObject).concat("")`, which doesn't fail, but would instead result in the String `"null"`.

However, **is this a good practice?** My first thought is that it seems like it might take longer to perform, since it's implicitly calling two methods, but it does help guarantee software that doesn't crash.

Comment: Are you using Java 7 or 6?

Comment: The good practice is to check whether or not myObject is null before calling toString

Comment: Years ago I remember learning about the `+""` and hearing (I think from a talk with Josh Bloch that he felt guilty about using it until he saw that the `java.net.*` Java Libraries use it in a few places

Comment: @Amir that should be an answer not a comment!

Comment: @MartinDinov No that is a comment. Null check is not the modern praxis. avoiding nulls is better

Comment: @AlexWien isn't that a bit too firm. I mean if I want to be pragmatic I'd consider what works best in each scenario. Avoiding nulls isn't always better.

Comment: After trying to track down some more authoritative source than my fragile memory, I think the advice appears to have pertained to converting `int`s to `String`s and also appears to be wrong (who knows if Josh Bloch was ever wrong, the guy literally wrote the book on Effective Java), but I think @RohitJain is on the right track with his answer.

Comment: It is modestly inefficient, but probably not a poor choice for the oddball cases where you need this sort of thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You certainly can do `myObject+""`. But as you already know, that requires some extra method invocation. That will depend upon the application you're using it in. Will that extra method invocation be a bottle-neck for the application? I guess that is rarely an issue. Or, to avoid that extra method call, you can directly use `String#valueOf()` method. But that would depend upon how you want to handle `null`s. I would certainly not proceed normally in these circumstances. At least log a message indicating `null` reference.

Also, if you're already on Java 7, then you can use [`Objects.toString(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%29) method, that handles `null` for you. Again, that method returns `"null"` for `null` references.

So, now it's your call. I've given you some option. You might want to throw exception, log message and proceed with `"null"` string, or some default string like `""`.

Comment: returning a "null" string would avoid the immediate threat of failing. But what if the content ("null") cause more problem or take the code through a more disastrous route?

Comment: @AmirKeibi Yes, that will depend upon OP how he wants to handle `null`. We can just provide him/her options.

Answer (score 3):

If you want that behavior, `String.valueOf(myObject)` gets you the same while being less hacky. But it also means that a `null` string and the string `"null"` are treated the same. It's usually better to check for null values explicitly, unless you're just print to a log or such. But in those cases, most methods take an Object reference and handle nulls for you (e.g. System.out.println, most logging frameworks, etc.)